# Use WebView or ImageView for best results?

Tags: java, android

I have 10000x10000 px large bitmap. I cut it into many images in Photoshop and made a `WebView` with html which contains these images.
But I can't test my application on old phones, because I have an SGS 3.

My question is: is the better map for exploring results `WebView` or `ImageView`?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Will your users be panning around this large bitmap? Do you need to support zoom?

Comment: Yeah. I need zoom. Users will drag and pinch to zoom image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `WebView` solves the problem for you, then I would use that. You won't need to design a flexible layout to hold a large number of `Views`, implement zooming and panning, etc. That's a substantial savings in development time. Making your app respond to clicks on the individual pieces of your large bitmap will take a bit of work since they're HTML elements, but (IMO) it's a better option than working with a large number of `ImageView`s.

If your question is more related to UI performance, that's harder to predict. `WebView` is optimized for displaying complex layouts and supporting the type of scrolling and scaling interactions that you mentioned. `ImageView` is a simple `View` that isn't trivial to extend for those types of interactions.

For my money: the `WebView` is best for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a custom view that implements pinch and zoom and supports subsampling large images and loading only the areas that are on screen. I was unable to find a suitable library so I built one. It uses BitmapRegionDecoder and therefore requires SDK 10 (Gingerbread). However, you don't need to cut the image up manually.

https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view